# Alignment of equals sign in multiple align environments

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align

I have multiple `align` environments in my document, separated by a small paragraph of text:

```
\begin{align*}
  foo &= something very very long compared to the other align
\end{align*}
explanation what I shall do now
\begin{align*}
  foo' &= foo + short
\end{align*}
```

As the text in the second `align` is considerably shorter, the `=` signs don't line up, which is to be expected.

Is there some way to make the two equals signs line up with eachother?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the `amsmath` documentation:

> The command `\intertext` is used for a short interjection of one of two lines of text in the middle of a multiple-line display structure ... Its salient feature is preservation of the alignment, which would not happen if you simply ended the display and then started it up again afterwards.  `\intertext` may only appear right after a `\\` or `\\*` command.

So your example would be:

```
\begin{align*}
  foo &= something very very long compared to the other align \\
\intertext{explanation what I shall do now}
  foo' &= foo + short
\end{align*}
```

The `breqn` package also has this capability via its `dsuspend` environment.

---

(Added in edit) From the comments, there appear to be a few different ways to achieve this effect.  So to help with choosing, here's a sample of all those that I'm aware of.  Anyone who knows more is welcome to either add directly to this answer or to make a comment and then I'll add it.  Here's the result:

[image: variations on a theme of intertext]

and here's the code that produced it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Two aligns}

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}
&= a e i + b f g + c d h - a f h - b d i - c e g
\end{align*}
%
Whilst for \(2 \times 2\) we have:
%
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
&= a d - b c
\end{align*}

\paragraph{One align, intertext preceeded by \textbackslash\textbackslash} 

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}
&= a e i + b f g + c d h - a f h - b d i - c e g \\
%
\intertext{Whilst for \(2 \times 2\) we have:}
%
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
&= a d - b c
\end{align*}

\paragraph{One align, intertext not preceeded by \textbackslash\textbackslash} 

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}
&= a e i + b f g + c d h - a f h - b d i - c e g
%
\intertext{Whilst for \(2 \times 2\) we have:}
%
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
&= a d - b c
\end{align*}

\paragraph{One align, shortintertext (mathtools)}

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}
&= a e i + b f g + c d h - a f h - b d i - c e g
%
\shortintertext{Whilst for \(2 \times 2\) we have:}
%
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
&= a d - b c
\end{align*}

\paragraph{Using dsuspend from breqn}
~

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}
= a e i + b f g + c d h - a f h - b d i - c e g
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dsuspend}
Whilst for \(2 \times 2\) we have:
\end{dsuspend}
\begin{dmath*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
= a d - b c
\end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Also note the `\shortintertext` from mathtools. Often `\intertext` produces excessive vertical spacing (in particular if the text is short).

Comment: @Villemoes: Very useful to know; I rarely use `\intertext` because of the excessive spacing.

Comment: @Herbert, @Villemoes: I've added a sample showing the various possibilities.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I think `mathtools` automatically loads `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to throw in a (e)plain-version as well:

```
\input eplain % merely for the command below
\leftdisplays % for making the picture smaller
$$ \def\vmatrix#1{\left|\matrix{#1}\right|}
  \eqalignno{
    \vmatrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f\cr g&h&i} &= aei + bfg + cdh - afh - bdi - ceg \cr
\noalign{\hbox{Whilst for $2 \times 2$ we have:}} % break away from the align
    \vmatrix{a&b\cr c&d} &= ad - bc
  }
$$
\bye
```

[image: breakalign]

Answer (score 3):

The following example shows a manual way of achieving the desired alignment between equation (1) and (2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Given that
\begin{equation}
  \text{Long left-hand side} = \mathrlap{a}
    \phantom{\text{Long right-hand side}.}
\end{equation}
where
\[
  b = \text{Some weird definition},
\]
it should be clear that
\begin{equation}
  \phantom{\text{Long left-hand side}}
  \mathllap{c} = \text{Long right-hand side}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The above example attempts to align two equations - (1) and (2) - with an additional, ad-hoc, alignment in-between (for whatever reason). The principle of this approach is to identify the longest item on the left-hand and right-hand side respectively, and add them as `\phantom`s to the equations that have shorter such sides. `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` (from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) provides the means to sneak in the shorter side visually over-top of the `\phantom` placement.

This approach might be helpful when the content inserted between the two alignments fail under `\intertext` or `\shortintertext`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I learned a lot from your link and in some cases it is indeed necessary.