# The formula alignment across a table column

Tags: tables, math-mode, vertical-alignment, align

I use the following code to produce a LaTeX output.

```
‎\documentclass[12pt]{report}‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎‎

‎\newcommand*\sumta[2]{\mathop {\sum} \limits_{#1}^{#2}}‎‎
‎\newcommand*\bnsar[2]{_{#1}^{#2}}‎‎

\begin{document}‎
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Time domain features}
\label{table.1}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
Feature & Formula \\ \hline
Mean value & ‎$‎\overline{x}=‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sumta{i=1}{N}x_i‎‎‎‎$‎  \\
Standard deviation & ‎$‎\sigma = ‎‎\sqrt{‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sumta{n=1}{N}(x_i - ‎\overline{x})^2‎‎‎}‎‎‎$‎  \\
Kurtosis & ‎$\text{K}=‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sumta{i=1}{N}‎\frac{(x_i‎‏-\overline{x})^4‎}{‎\sigma‎^4}‎‎‎$‎  \\
Skewness & ‎$\text{Sk} = ‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sumta{i=1}{N}‎\frac{(x_i-‎\overline{x})^3‎}{‎\sigma‎^3}‎‎‎$‎ \\
Root mean square & ‎$\text{RMS} = ‎\sqrt{‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sumta{i=1}{N}x‎\bnsar{i}{2}‎‎‎}‎$‎ \\
Crest factor & ‎$\text{Crf} = ‎\frac{\max \text{value}}{\text{RMS}}‎$‎ \\
Peak to Peak value & ‎$\text{PPV} = \max \text{value} - \min \text{value}$‎ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}‎
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, each row is consisted of two columns. The expressions in the right column are all in Math mode. How may I align the equations for a specific operator across a column in LaTeX? For example, I want the equation marks to be aligned vertically across the column cells to produce an output alike the picture below.

[image]

I've reviewed [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282139/aligning-inside-a-table-across-a-column) suggestions available, but they simply are not what I mean! Please help me through the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

- you should provide complete small document with all your definitions used in table
- given one doesn't work
- i add two packages used for improved your table looks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}   % new
\setcellgapes{5pt}             % new
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} % new


\begin{document}
    ‎\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\makegapedcells    % new
    \caption{Time domain features}
\label{table.1}
    \begin{tabular}{l| >{$}r<{$} @{\hspace{2.2pt}} >{$}l<{$}}
    \hline
Feature             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Formula}                               \\ 
    \hline
Mean value          & ‎‎\overline{x}  & = ‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i            \\
Standard deviation  & ‎‎\sigma        & = ‎‎\sqrt{‎\frac{1}{N}
                                        ‎\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i - ‎\overline{x})^2‎‎‎}   \\
Kurtosis            & \mathrm{K}    & = ‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sum_{i=1}^{N}
                                        ‎\frac{(x_i‎‏-\overline{x})^4‎}{‎\sigma‎^4}   \\
Skewness            & ‎\mathrm{Sk}   & = ‎\frac{1}{N}‎\sum_{i=1}^{N}
                                        ‎\frac{(x_i-‎\overline{x})^3‎}{‎\sigma‎^3}‎‎‎   \\
Root mean square    & ‎\mathrm{RMS}  & = ‎\sqrt{‎\frac{1}{N} 
                                        ‎\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_-\overline{x})^2 }    \\
Crest factor        & \mathrm{Crf}  & = ‎\frac{\max \mathrm{value}}{\mathrm{RMS}}‎  \\
Peak to Peak value  & \mathrm{PPV}  & = \max \mathrm{value} - \min \mathrm{value} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there some other ways to get the same result?

Comment: what is wrong with this: it is simple :-). it might exist, but i don't aware on it.

Comment: For coloring the rows, look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378268/makegapedcells-disables-rowcolor, `\makegapedcells` have problem with coloring the table.

Comment: @Qaher, where you have any table coloring? i'm aware of this problem.

Comment: It was because I've asked about other available solutions to get the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Some improvements with `booktabs` and medium sized formulæ with `nccmath`. In addition, I think `\bar{x}` looks better than `\overline{x}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs} % new%
\setcellgapes{5pt} % new
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} % new
\newcommand\msum{\medop\sum\limits}

\begin{document}
    ‎\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering%
\makegapedcells % new
    \caption{Time domain features}
\label{table.1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r @{\qquad}>{$}r<{$} @{} >{${}}l<{$}@{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Feature} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Formula} \\
    \midrule
Mean value & ‎‎\bar{x} & = ‎\mfrac{1}{N}‎\msum_{i=1}^{N}x_i \\
Standard deviation & ‎‎\sigma & = ‎‎\sqrt{‎\mfrac{1}{N}
                                       ‎\msum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i - ‎\bar{x})^2‎‎‎} \\
Kurtosis & \mathrm{K} & = ‎\mfrac{1}{N}\medop‎\sum_{i=1}^{N}
                                        ‎\mfrac{(x_i‎‏-\bar{x})^4‎}{‎\sigma‎^4} \\
Skewness & ‎\mathrm{Sk} & = ‎\mfrac{1}{N}‎\msum_{i=1}^{N}
                                        ‎\mfrac{(x_i-‎\bar{x})^3‎}{‎\sigma‎^3}‎‎‎ \\
Root mean square & ‎\mathrm{RMS} & = ‎\sqrt{‎\mfrac{1}{N}
                                        \msum_{i=1}^{N} (x_-\bar{x})^2 } \\
Crest factor & \mathrm{Crf} & = ‎\mfrac{\max \mathrm{value}}{\mathrm{RMS}}‎ \\
Peak to Peak value & \mathrm{PPV} & = \max \mathrm{value} - \min \mathrm{value} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}‎

\end{document}
```

[image]