# Alignment between different subequation environments

Tags: math-mode, align, vertical-alignment, alignment, subequations

I have two consecutive subequation environments with no text in between, I would like to align the four equations in the two environments.

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\newcommand{\average}[2][2]{{%
  \mspace{#1mu}\mspace{#1mu}\mspace{#1mu}%
  \overline{\mspace{-#1mu}#2\mspace{-#1mu}\mspace{-#1mu}\relax}\mspace{#1mu}%
}}


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \epsilon_{11}' &= {\average{n'}}^2 - \average{n''}^2\\
    \epsilon_{11}'' &= 2 \average{n'} \average{n''}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\useshortskip
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \epsilon_{12}' &= \average{n'} \Delta n'' + \average{n''} \Delta n'\\
    \epsilon_{12}'' &= \average{n''} \Delta n'' - \average{n'} \Delta n'
\end{align}
\end{subequations}


\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Code output]

Aligning all of the equals signs would look better, but I want to maintain the numbering as it is now to demonstrate which quantities are grouped.

**Update:**

Using the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701782/4427 does solve my alignment problem, but referring to the grouped equations collectively only works for the first set of subequations in the environment.

Updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\newcommand{\average}[1]{{%
  \mspace{6mu}%
  \overline{\mspace{-2mu}#1\mspace{-4mu}\relax}\mspace{3mu}%
}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stepsubequation}{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \stepcounter{parentequation}%
    \protected@xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
    \ifdefined\theHparentequation
      \protected@xdef\theHparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
    \fi
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq_eps11}
\begin{align}
    \epsilon_{11}' &= {\average{n'}}^2 - \average{n''}^2\\
    \epsilon_{11}'' &= 2 \average{n'} \average{n''}\\
    \stepsubequation \label{eq_eps12}
    \epsilon_{12}' &= \average{n'} \Delta n'' + \average{n''} \Delta n'\\
    \epsilon_{12}'' &= \average{n''} \Delta n'' - \average{n'} \Delta n'
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Collective reference to equations~\ref{eq_eps11} works correctly, to equations~\ref{eq_eps12} includes the subequation label.


\end{document}
```

Updated output:

[image: Updated output]

I tried the second solution from this question as well but this produces an undefined control sequence error pointing to the line with \begin{document}, I'm not well versed enough in TeX to understand what's going on unfortunately. The pdf output also seems to have some text from the preamble leaking into it somehow:

[image: Output with second method from other question]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I think that https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701782/4427 would help

Comment: Thanks @egreg ! I found some of your other answers when I was searching, but this one didn't come up for some reason. It solves my problem exactly though. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @egreg I found a  small problem with the labeling/referencing of the second set of subequations in the environment, please see my update to the original question for info.

Comment: @s.jenga I added code to support “sublabels”, see the edited post.

Comment: @egreg works perfectly, thank you so much!